# Switch language with a URL in Ruby on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, url, internationalization, locale

I have a site in both French and English. I want the user to be able to switch language on the fly when they click a link in the header. Pretty straightforward.

I have followed the Ruby on Rails 3 guide, and I have this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
before_filter :set_locale
def set_locale
    I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
end

protect_from_forgery

  def default_url_options(options={})
  logger.debug "default_url_options is passed options: #{options.inspect}\n"
  { :locale => I18n.locale }
   end
end
```

My routes look like this:

```
scope "(:locale)", :locale => /en|fr/ do

match 'home' => 'home#index'
match 'home/ajax_twitter' => 'home#ajax_twitter'
match 'equipe' => 'equipe#index'
match 'equipe/sylvain' => 'equipe#sylvain'
match 'equipe/benoit' => 'equipe#benoit'
match 'equipe/stephane' => 'equipe#stephane'
match 'equipe/suemarie' => 'equipe#suemarie'
match 'equipe/regis' => 'equipe#regis'
match 'equipe/fred' => 'equipe#fred'

match 'equipe/callback' => 'equipe#callback'
match 'equipe/auth' => 'equipe#auth'
match 'equipe/ajax_contact' => 'equipe#ajax_contact'

match 'linkedinauth/callback' => 'linkedinAuth#callback'
match 'linkedinauth/init_auth' => 'linkedinAuth#init_auth'

match 'mission' => 'mission#index'
match 'service' => 'service#index'
match 'developmen' => 'developmen#index'

match 'contact' => 'contact#index'

match 'mandats' => 'mandats#index'
end

match '/:locale' => "home#index"
```

And in my view I do this:

```
<% if I18n.locale == I18n.default_locale %>
  <%= link_to "English", '/en'%>

<% else %>
  <%= link_to "Français", '/fr'%>

<%end%>
```

All works well in the home page, but if I try to switch language while I'm in a specific controller, I get returned to the home page. I tried to add this:

```
<% if I18n.locale == I18n.default_locale %>
  <%= link_to "English", '/en/' + params[:controller]%>

<% else %>
  <%= link_to "Français", '/fr/' + params[:controller]%>

<%end%>
```

This fixes the controller, but if we are in a specific action and switch language again, I get back to the 'index' of this controller.

My question: What is the best way to deal with this?

I guess I could implement something in the ApplicationController (filter) to check if a controller / action / id is passed and append it to the locale. Or can I do this in the routes.rb?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Oh well, finally found a way I like...

```
<% if I18n.locale == I18n.default_locale %>
  <%= link_to "English", { :locale=>'en' } %>

<% else %>
  <%= link_to "Français", { :locale=>'fr' } %>

<%end%>
```

As simple as this!

Vive Ruby on Rails!

Answer (score 16):

If you have scope route like this that covers all the localized routes:

```
scope "/:locale" do
  ...
end
```

If you are in a page inside that scoped route e.g. '/en/...' you can create links to change the locale without changing your current site location like this:

```
<%= link_to "Français", params.merge({:locale => :fr}) %>
<%= link_to "English", params.merge({:locale => :en}) %>
```

Comment: For some reason using symbols (eg. `:en`) causes `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {...})` on **subsequent** clicks (tested in Rails 3.2.12). Using strings instead solves the issue (`:locale => 'en'`).

Comment: this is a more helpful answer because it deals with existing context, i.e. the params. and merging them with the locale, which is a meta-level param...

Answer (score 8):

I believe this way makes it cleaner. So here it goes:

**config/application.rb**

```
I18n.available_locales = [:en, :pt, :es, :de]
```

Create a .yml file for each :locale on **config/locales/:locale.yml**

Don't forget to add this on each of the locale.yml files, this is how the `link_to t(lang)` is translated when changing between locations.

```
en:
  en: "English"
  pt: "Portuguese"
  es: "Spanish"
  de: "German"
```

Add the list of locales to your html:

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
    <%= t(I18n.locale) %> # Current selected locales
    <span class="caret"></span>
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li class="header">Select a language</li>
        <% I18n.available_locales.each do |lang| %> # Array of available locales
        <li>
        <%= link_to t(lang), change_locale_path(lang) %> # Each locale URL param and name
        </li>
        <% end %>
</ul>
```

So now you can see all the locales that you added to **config/application.rb**

**config/routes.rb**:

```
match 'lang/:locale', to: 'index#change_locale', as: :change_locale, via: [:get]
```

**app/controllers/index_controller.rb**

```
def change_locale
    l = params[:locale].to_s.strip.to_sym
    l = I18n.default_locale unless I18n.available_locales.include?(l)
    cookies.permanent[:my_locale] = l
    redirect_to request.referer || root_url
end
```

**app/controllers/application_controller.rb**

```
before_action :set_locale

def set_locale
      if cookies[:my_locale] && I18n.available_locales.include?(cookies[:grolla_locale].to_sym)
        l = cookies[:my_locale].to_sym
      else
        l = I18n.default_locale
        cookies.permanent[:my_locale] = l
      end
      I18n.locale = l
    end
```

Answer (score 3):

Say that you want a selector for all the languages. E.g. You are in `en` locale and you also have `fr` and `es` locales

In `application_helper.rb` (or any other helper in /app/helpers/)

```
def alternate_locales
  I18n.available_locales.map{|l|
    yield(l)
  }.join.html_safe
end
```

Now anywhere in the view:

```
<% alternate_locales do |l| %>
   <li class="language <%= l %>"><%= link_to(l,locale: l) %></li>
<% end %>
```

If the user locale is english, an current URL is `www.example.com/en/path/` This will generate:

```
<li class="language fr"><a href="www.example.com/fr/path/">fr</a></li>
<li class="language es"><a href="www.example.com/es/path/">es</a></li>
<li class="language en"><a href="www.example.com/en/path/">en</a></li>
```

Plus, if you want to have the link[rel="alternate"] links in the header:

```
<% alternate_locales do |l| %>
  <link rel="alternate" hreflang="<%= l %>" href="<%= url_for(locale: l) %>">
<% end %>
```

That will generate:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr" href="www.example.com/fr/path/">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="es" href="www.example.com/es/path/">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="www.example.com/en/path/">
```